# Command button stops to work after validation fail

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

Im my web app i have the following form that opens up in a dialog:

```
<!-- Event edit -->
    <p:dialog id="editEvent" 
              widgetVar="dlgEdit" 
              modal="true"
              resizable="true" 
              closable="true"
              header="Edit event">
        <p:panelGrid columns="1" 
                     styleClass="gridNoLine">
            <p:panelGrid columns="1">
                <p:messages id="mEditMessages"
                            closable="true" 
                            redisplay="true"/>
            </p:panelGrid>
            <p:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="gridNoLine">
                <h:outputLabel value="..." />
                <p:inputText value="#{eventBean.event.eventName}"
                             required="true"
                             requiredMessage="XXX"/>
            </p:panelGrid>
            <p:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="gridNoLine">
                <h:outputLabel value="..." />
                <p:inputTextarea value="#{eventBean.event.eventDescription}"
                                 required="true"
                                 requiredMessage="XXX" />
            </p:panelGrid>

            ...

            <p:commandButton id="cbUpdateEvent" 
                             value="Update"
                             actionListener="#{eventBean.update}"
                             oncomplete="handleAction(xhr, status, args);"
                             process="@form"
                             update="mEditMessages OTHERCONTROLS"/>

        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:dialog>
```

This dialog is opened from a commandButton column for each row of a DataTable as the following code shows:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{eventBean.events}" 
             var="event">
    <p:column styleClass="commandColumn">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputLabel value="Editar"/>
        </f:facet>
        <p:commandButton image="ui-icon-pencil" 
                     title="Edit"
                     update="editEvent"
                     oncomplete="dlgEdit.show();"
                     process="@this">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{event}" target="#{eventBean.event}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
    ...
 </p:dataTable>
```

The problem is: When i open the dialog, clear a random field (just to test validation) and click the update button a warning message shows on the dialog. Fine. But when i clear another field and click the update button, the required message associated with that control doesn't show. And then when i close the dialog and click once again in any alter column of any row nothing happens. I can see the following message on the browser console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

OBS: If i click the edit command and do not modify any field and just close, the app works fine and i can view the edit dialog for other records.

UPDATE:
Here is the template.xhtml code:

```
<h:body>
    <div class="structure"> 
        <div class="top">
        </div>
        <!--Base Menu -->
        <h:form id="menu">
            <div class="menu">
                <p:menubar autoDisplay="true" >
                    ...
                </p:menubar>
            </div>
        </h:form>
        <!-- Conteúdo -->
        <div class="left_content">

            <ui:insert name="content">
            </ui:insert>

        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</h:body>
```

And here is the handleAction code:

```
function handleAction(xhr, status, args){
    switch(args.key){
        case 'update': 
            dlgEdit.hide();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of primefaces is this?

Comment: try to move the `h:form` inside the `p:dialog` (but make sure you wont get nested forms)

Comment: That's not a JSF error, but a JS error. Which scripts do you have all in your view apart from the auto-included ones?

Comment: @kolossus I'm using primefaces 3.4.2

Comment: @Daniel The problem is that in my template page (template.xhtml) i have a form around ui:insert. So if i put one more form inside the template client ui:define, i'll probably run into problems.

Comment: @BalusC I don't have any included scripts on my page besides primefaces.js, jquery.js and schedule.js which are include by primefaces.

Comment: @mnatan.brito try adding `appendToBody="true"` to your dialog and placing a `h:form` inside it...

Comment: could you show us the code of your `handleAction(xhr, status, args)` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the error. I just was importing the primefaces jar twice as pointed [here](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=24368). I had a primefaces-3.4.jar in my WEB-INF/lib folder and in my pom.xml file. I did remove the jar inside WEB-INF/lib and everything went right.